# ¿Cómo usar Tomcat en IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea

No me gusta el NeatBeans y prefiero usar Tomcat en IntelliJ. Me gustaría saber cómo, ya que no he conseguido información clara en internet.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Visitaste el [tutorial ofrecido por Jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tutorials/working-with-apache-tomcat/creating-new-application/)? Sería útil que expliques qué no entiendes para poder hacer hincapié en eso.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.